# Bandpass active filter design with differential input

Tags: power-supply, filter, differential

I want to make a bandpass filter with a differential input. The filter I wanted is ready, but I made it for a single input. How do I make this filter suitable for differential inputs?

The filter I made:

[image: the filter I made]

Comment: Use a decent audio transformer at the input --> massive common mode rejection is a big bonus along with another big bonus of signal isolation.

Comment: Why not use an active 2nd order filter, instead of the two 1st order sections (the overall response is, at the very best, a critically damped response).

Comment: I'm just starting to learn about these issues. @aconcernedcitizen , 2nd will the input signal be differential input when I use an active filter of order? Could you you give some detailed information? Thank you.

Comment: @Andyaka Can you tell me some sample circuits? I'm just learning about these things.

Comment: @dmrmuhammet unfortunately this is not what this site is about. It's a question and answer site.

Comment: Regarding Andy's suggestion (a good one). Add the audio transformer to the input of your filter. Apply your differential signal to one winding, The other winding goes to your single-ended bandpass filter. Perhaps its not the cheapest solution, but only adds one part.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you very much. I will try.